# Ban user based on IP without allowing Admin to access IP

Tags: node.js

I am working on a software which I'd like to have the ability to ban a user based on their IP address so that the user may not easily create another account after a ban, but I'd also like to make the IP address inaccessible to administrators for user privacy reasons.

Does Humanity currently possess any solutions to such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat IP addresses like passwords are often treated where you perform some non-reversible operation on the IP address (such as a cryptographic hash) and that's what you store in your database.  Then, when you want to check an incoming IP address vs. the database, you perform the same non-reversible operation on the test IP address and look up that result in the database.

In this way, you can test if an IP address that produces the same hash is in your database, but there is no way to get the actual IP addresses from the database.  You will have to make sure that the hash you are using is extremely unlikely to create the same hash value for multiple IP addresses.

You should be aware that there are some situations (such as corporate proxies) where multiple users may appear to come from the same IP address, thus banning a user solely based on IP address may end up enforcing a ban on innocent users that come from a closely related part of the network.

You should also be aware that an IP address is like a "weak password" and the hash could be "cracked" for a given IP address by just trying all possible IP addresses until you found one that had a hash that matches the one in the database.  If your only unique identifier is the IP address (and there's nothing else you can add to that), then there isn't much you can do about that.  If you can combine something else with the IP address to make it more unique, then you can make it less crackable.

Comment: Unfortunately IPv4 address are too short (4 bytes) and can be easily brute-forced. I'm not sure whether IPv6 is fine eater.